# Unable to get storage account key with Azure Fluent

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-fluent-api

I created a storage account with Azure Fluent SDK. But after I created the storage account, I wanted to get the name and key to build the connection string that I can use to access the storage account. The problem is that the 'Key' property is a Guid, not the key shown in the Azure Portal.

This is how I create the storage account.

```
IStorageAccount storage = azure.StorageAccounts.Define(storageAccountName)
    .WithRegion(Region.USEast)
    .WithNewResourceGroup(rgName)
    .Create();
```

How can I get the proper Key to build the connection string?

Comment: Was the below response helpful to you Keisha ?

Comment: This worked for me thanks. I thought I accepted the answer before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do it via the below code, this [**documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/dotnet-sdk-azure-authenticate?view=azure-dotnet) also shows the use of Fluent but only the auth methods:

```
    // Get a storage account
var storage = azure.StorageAccounts.GetByResourceGroup("myResourceGroup", "myStorageAccount");

// Extract the keys
var storageKeys = storage.GetKeys();

// Build the connection string
string storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;"
        + "AccountName=" + storage.Name
        + ";AccountKey=" + storageKeys[0].Value
        + ";EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

// Connect
var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);

// Do things with the account here...
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Helped me